# can objects contain movieclips in flash actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an array, which contains a bunch of objects. Those objects have a bunch of different properties. But one of the things I want each object to contain is a movieclip, but I'm having trouble getting the movieclip into the object. Basically what I have is this (very simplified):

```
var groupArray:Array = new Array();

for (var i=0;i<numGroups;i++){
var groupObject:Object = new Object();
groupArray.push(groupObject)
}
```

and what I want to do is this (later in the code):

```
var groupClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
groupArray[i].addChild(groupClip)
```

But this doesn't work. How do I make the movieclip part of the object?

Comment: var groupObject:UIComponent= new UIComponent();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this is what you do:

```
var array:Array = new Array();
var length:int = 5;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    var object:Object = new Object();
    array.push(object);

}// end for

var movieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
array[0].movieClip = movieClip;

trace(array[0].movieClip)// output: [object MovieClip];
```

the previous is the same as the following(except with only one element in the array instead of five):

```
var array:Array = new Array();

var object:Object = new Object;
var movieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

object.movieClip = movieClip; // or object["movieClip"] = movieClip;

array.push(object);

trace(array[0].movieClip)// output: [object MovieClip];
```

Comment: no - I want it to be array contains objects contains movieclip, not array contains movieclip and object

Comment: @mheaver but it is an array that contains an object and that object contains a property called `movieClip` that was assigned an instance of `MovieClip`, I'll update the answer to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: Ah - thanks yep - that helps. Totally worked. Didn't realize you could just create a movieclip link that. So does array[0].movieClip just become a reference to the movieClip, or are there now 2 movieClips?

Comment: It only has 1. Think of it this way, you created a property on your object and then assigned a new instance of `MovieClip` to that property as its value. So in other words, that object contains a property called `movieClip` that contains an instance of `MovieClip`.

Answer (score 1):

The addChild only exist for classes that inherits from DisplayObjectContainer, and Object doesn't.

Examples of classes that inherits from DisplayObjectContainer: Sprite and MovieClip.

You can read more about it here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()

Comment: Yes! The poster wants var groupObject:Sprite= new Sprite(); in order to use DisplayObject and DisplayObjectContainer functionality. You can't make a DisplayObjectContainer directly since it's an abstract base class.

Answer (score 0):

Objects can contain anything.  You can dynamically create or access any property, existing or not, on an object at runtime.  Your first problem is that Object doesn't have a "push" function.  To assign anything to an Object, you do so using key/value notation.

```
object["foo"] = new MovieClip();
trace(object.foo);
trace(object["foo"]);
```

EDIT : either my earlier reading was off or you edited the sample so this no longer applies... <strike>But it looks like you *want* groupObject to be an array since you're using the i variable to try to reference a clip... so why not make it an array?  That way you can use the push function and everything is numerically indexed like you appear to expect it to be anyway.</strike>

It's difficult to be sure, but it also looks like you're going to have a logic error down at the last line of your code.  Where is that i variable being set?  Also, it looks like you're trying to call addChild on an Object rather than on the movieclip you think you're storing... that won't work becuase Object doesn't have the addChild function.

Comment: I believe by *contain* the OP meant a DisplayObjectContainer parent-child relationship, not just owning a reference.

Comment: well - what I want to say is to add a pre existing movieclip to a preexisting object, so using your example: object -> addMovieClip(foo) - only addMovieClip is obviously not valid syntax, so what is the proper syntax?

Comment: @mheavers what do you mean precisely by "add a preexisting movieclip to an object"?  By this is the expected result that the movieclip appears on the user's screen?  Or are you simply hoping to have a handy collection from which you retrieve movieclips for further use?